# The equation of an ellipse

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I have a couple of questions regarding ellipses.

*Get the equation of the ellips*

- With Foci $(\pm 3,0)$ and which goes through $(2,\sqrt{2})$. This one I didn't understand AT ALL. I need some explanation

Valentin gave an answer I originally deemed correct, however, you can see my objections in the comments of the answer.

Comment: Do you mean goes through $(2,\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: @littleO yes, I do mean that, I'll edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of an ellipse whose major and minor axes coincide with the Cartesian axes is 
\begin{equation}
\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1.
\end{equation}
The distance from the center  to either focus is $f$ where
\begin{equation}
f^2 = a^2 - b^2.
\end{equation}
We are given that $f = 3$, from which we conclude that
$b^2 = a^2 - 9$.  The equation of our ellipse reduces to
\begin{equation}
\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{a^2 - 9} = 1.
\end{equation}
Now we plug in the point $(2,\sqrt{2})$ and obtain
\begin{equation}
\frac{4}{a^2} + \frac{2}{a^2 - 9} = 1.
\end{equation}
There are four values of $a$ that satisfy this equation, and we pick the one that is larger than $3$:
\begin{equation}
a = 2 \sqrt{3}.
\end{equation}

How to solve for $a$ in more detail:
\begin{align*}
&\frac{4}{a^2} + \frac{2}{a^2 - 9} = 1 \\
\implies& 4 + \frac{2a^2}{a^2 - 9} = a^2 \\
\implies& 4(a^2 - 9) + 2a^2 = a^2(a^2 - 9) \\
\implies& a^4 - 15a^2 + 36 = 0 \\
\implies& (a^2 - 12)(a^2 - 3) = 0 \\
\implies& a = \pm 2\sqrt{3} \text{ or } a = \pm \sqrt{3}.
\end{align*}

Comment: How do you know which values satisfy the equation? Is there a handy way to get those values?

Comment: I just edited my answer to show that part in more detail.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Last question before I award you the deserved bounty, what is wrong about Valentin's method?

Comment: Valentin correctly set up the equation $a^4 - 15a^2 + 36 = 0$, but his next step did not follow and was an error.  It would have been correct if he'd said $a^2 = 12$ or $a^2 = 3$.

Comment: The bounty is yours (in 23 hours)

Comment: Good luck on your test!

Answer (score 2):

We know, the sum of the distances from any point $P(h,k)$ on the ellipse to those two foci is constant and equal to the major axis $(2a)$.

As $(2,\sqrt2)$ lies on the ellipse, $2a=\sqrt{(3-2)^2+(0-\sqrt 2)^2}+\sqrt{(-3-2)^2+(0-\sqrt 2)^2}=\sqrt 3+3\sqrt3=4\sqrt3$

So, $\sqrt{(h-3)^2+(k-0)^2}+\sqrt{\{h-(-3)\}^2+(k-0)^2}=2a=4\sqrt 3$

or ,$\sqrt{(h-3)^2+(k-0)^2}=4\sqrt 3-\sqrt{\{h-(-3)\}^2+(k-0)^2}$

On squaring, $(h-3)^2+(k-0)^2=48+(h+3)^2+k^2-8\sqrt3\sqrt{(h+3)^2+k^2}$

or, $8\sqrt3\sqrt{(h+3)^2+k^2}=48+12h$

On squaring and simplification,
 $$h^2+4k^2=12\space or \space \frac {h^2}{12}+\frac{k^2}3=1$$

So, the locus of  $P(h,k)$ is $$\frac {x^2}{12}+\frac{y^2}3=1$$

---

Alternatively,

$a=2\sqrt 3$.

Here $ae=3,e=\frac3{2\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt3}2$

If $2b$ is the minor axis,$b^2=a^2(1-e^2)=(2\sqrt3)^2\left(1-\frac3 4\right)=3$

We [know](http://www.algebralab.org/lessons/lesson.aspx?file=Algebra_conics_ellipse.xml), the midpoint of the segment connecting the foci is the centre of the ellipse, so here the centre is $\frac{3-3}2,\frac{0+0}2$ i.e., $(0,0)$

Again, the major axis is the segment that contains both foci.

Here the equation of the major axis is $\frac{y-0}{x-3}=\frac{0-0}{\{3-(-3)\}}$ i.e, $y=0$ the X axis.

So, the required equation of the ellipse is $$\frac{(x-0)^2}{(2\sqrt3)^2}+\frac{(y-0)^2}{3}=1 $$

Answer (score 1):

Your first solution is correct, though in case of the ellipse $a^2=b^2+c^2$ not directly by Pythagoras theorem, but rather by definition of $b$.

It is this definition that you need to use in the second part where $c=3$, so

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2-9}=1$$

Now that you are given the point (assume it is $(2,\sqrt{2})$) through which the ellipse passes, substitute its coordinates in the equation and solve for $a$.
$$\frac{4}{a^2}+\frac{2}{a^2-9}=1$$

Comment: Oh, is it that simple? I'm going crazy. I have missed an entire semester, I am almost finished in doing 3 months of maths in 2 days.. sorry if you see some stupid questions once in a while

Comment: I actually discovered I don't know how to solve $\dfrac{4}{a^2} + \dfrac{2}{a^2-9} = 1$ ... can you show me?

Comment: But what is $b$? Is it $4$? But if it's $4$, than how can $a^2-9$ equal $b^2$?

Comment: How can $c$ be bigger than $a$? This is a wrong answer!